# Code won't fully run for some reason

Tags: python, sympy

I am writing code for a math calculator, and am running into a problem. When I ask the user to input a function to derive, and they input a number and then x, like 3x, instead of 3*x. The code crashes because it cannot parse it. To get around this I have a function to sanitize it, but it won't even run for some reason.

```
class Derivatives:
    def __init__(self):
        x=sympy.Symbol('x')
        self.func=self.clean_func((input("Enter f(x): ")))
        print(self.func)
        print(sympy.diff(self.func, x))

    def clean_func(self, func):
        clean_func=""
        print("c")            
        for i in range(len(func)):
            if func[i].isalpha or isinstance(func[i], int) or func[i] in self.math_symbols :
                if func[i]== "^" :
                    clean_func+="**"
                else:
                    clean_func+=func[i]
                for c in range(48, 57) :
                    if func[i:i+1] == (chr(c) + 'x') :
                        clean_func+="*"         #helps with parsing
        return clean_func
```

and I get this error in `a=Derivatives()`

```
Enter f(x): 3x
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-48-f4cd19afbde9>", line 1, in <module>
    a=Derivatives()

  File "/Volumes/PROJECTS/M_series.py", line 71, in __init__
    x=sympy.Symbol('x')

  File "/Users/thomastierney/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sympy/core/function.py", line 1691, in diff
    return Derivative(f, *symbols, **kwargs)

  File "/Users/thomastierney/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sympy/core/function.py", line 1018, in __new__
    expr = sympify(expr)

  File "/Users/thomastierney/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sympy/core/sympify.py", line 324, in sympify
    raise SympifyError('could not parse %r' % a, exc)

SympifyError: Sympify of expression 'could not parse '3x'' failed, because of exception being raised:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

A few problems:

1. Using `func` as the name of a string is misleading (Python allows first-order functions, therefore you would expect it to actually *be* a function); let's call it `fn_str` instead.
2. If `clean_func` worked properly, it would return a `sympy`-parseable string - which you then pass to `diff` without converting from a string to a function.
3. The construction

   ```
   for i in range(len(mystring)):
       do_something(mystring[i])
   ```

   is more clearly written as

   ```
   for ch in mystring:
       do_something(ch)
   ```
4. `isinstance(func[i], int)` doesn't work because `func[i]` is a one-character string, not an integer. Try `str.isdecimal()` instead.
5. `self.math_symbols` is not defined.
6. Python strings are immutable; every time you do `mystring += ch` it actually creates an entirely new string. Because of this, it is much more efficient to append to a list of string-chunks and then `"".join()` them when finished.
7. `for c in range(48, 57)`: Python ranges do not include the `end` value, ie this will produce 48, 49, 50, ... 56. This means chr(57) ie "9" is never tested for.
8. Similarly, string slices do not include the `end` offset, so `func[i:i+1]` is one character, exactly equivalent to `func[i]`. You meant `func[i:i+2]`.
9. Also, something like `3.` is a valid Python float, but your code will not catch `3.x`. Doing proper tokenization instead of character-by-character comparison would catch that.
10. The class is not a Derivative; you are trying to stuff your program into a mislabeled class.

A cleaned-up version:

```
import string
import sympy

# This could easily be just a function;
# I made it a class to keep the namespace clean
class FnStrCleaner:
    # valid characters
    NUMCHARS   = set(string.digits + ".")
    VARCHARS   = set(string.ascii_letters)
    OPCHARS    = set("()+-*/^")
    LEGALCHARS = NUMCHARS | VARCHARS | OPCHARS

    @classmethod
    def clean(cls, fn_str):
        # generator expression - skip nonlegal chars
        good_chars = (ch for ch in fn_str if ch in cls.LEGALCHARS)
        out = []
        # simple FSM to process character stream
        prev_num = False   # preceding character was part of a number
        for ch in good_chars:
            if prev_num:
                if ch in cls.NUMCHARS:
                    out.append(ch)
                    # prev_num = True
                elif ch in cls.VARCHARS:
                    out.append('*' + ch)
                    prev_num = False
                else:  # ch in cls.OPCHARS
                    out.append(ch)
                    prev_num = False
            else:
                if ch in cls.NUMCHARS:
                    out.append(ch)
                    prev_num = True
                elif ch in cls.VARCHARS:
                    out.append(ch)
                    # prev_num = False
                else:  # ch in cls.OPCHARS
                    out.append('**' if ch == '^' else ch)
                    # prev_num = False
        return "".join(out)

def get_function(prompt, locals=None):
    fn_str = input(prompt)
    fn_str = FnStrCleaner.clean(fn_str)
    return sympy.sympify(fn_str, locals=locals)

def main():
    x  = sympy.Symbol("x")
    f  = get_function("Enter f(x): ", {'x': x})
    df = sympy.diff(f, x)
    print("f(x) =", f)
    print("f'(x) =", df)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

which runs like

```
Enter f(x): 29x^3 + 12x^2 - 9x + 5
f(x) = 29*x**3 + 12*x**2 - 9*x + 5
f'(x) = 87*x**2 + 24*x - 9
```

Comment: So I took your clean func and put it in my math class, because this is a class with a lot of sub classes, so Ill be cleaning a lot of fn_str, then just derivatives. However, I dont think I am able to access it because its out side of my derivative class

Comment: I have tried to just do Math.clean(fn_str), but I get that it is missing the agrument 'fn_str', so I am confused

Comment: It should work fine as part of the Math class so long as (a) it remains a class method, (b) it has access to NUMCHARS, VARCHARS, OPCHARS, LEGALCHARS. Can you share your current actual code? hugh_bothwell at hotmail dot com

Comment: ... although this looks a lot like #10 above: there is no reason why FnStrCleaner should be part of your Math class. Why not just leave it as is?

Comment: Just emailed you, sorry it got messed up.